# Create/Extend new Ribbon with the client OM

Tags: client-object-model, ribbon

I want to integrate an existing LOB application into SharePoint using JavaScript.

To give the user a single user-experience, I would like to add an application specific ribbon to the current page. I've searched the docs/web but can't find any starting point on how to go about creating a new ribbon from scratch using the js OM.

I don't want to use the server side way for the ribbon creation, as I want to keep the deployment footprint minimal.

Can somebody point me in the direction on how to get started with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Turns out I was wrong. You **can** actually add ribbon items using the JS Client Object Model. Please see the following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185004.aspx

---

<s>I doubt you can do this with the JS Client Object Model.</s>

You can however do this using `CustomAction` element in the Elements.xml file

Here are some links to get you started building your own personal ribbon:
http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/01/customizing-ribbon-part-1-creating-tabs.html

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfrost/archive/2009/11/06/adding-custom-button-to-the-sharepoint-2010-ribbon.aspx

http://koenvosters.wordpress.com/2009/11/05/howto-add-a-button-to-the-ribbon-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: thanks. was hoping I could stay away from the server for the ribbon definition. then that's just the way it is..

Comment: Hi @AyKarsi turns out I was wrong. Check out my updated answer.